# How to post new host with variables to inventory in AAP API?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible Automation Platform (AAP) server. I have a task where I need to create a new host in an inventory on the AAP via the Rest API. I'm following [this documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/automation-controller/latest/html/controllerapi/api_ref.html#/Inventories/Inventories_inventories_hosts_create). Here's my task:

```yaml
- name: Add new host
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://{{ aap_fqdn }}/api/v2/inventories/{{ inventory }}/hosts/"
    user: '{{ user }}'
    password: '{{ pass }}'
    method: POST
    body:
      name: "host_1"
      variables:
        ansible_host: "192.168.0.1"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
```

This task fails with the following error:

```json
"json": {
  "variables": [
    "Not a valid string."
  ]
},
"msg": "Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request",
```

I don't understand how "variables" could be an invalid string when [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/automation-controller/latest/html/controllerapi/api_ref.html#/Inventories/Inventories_inventories_hosts_create:%7E:text=variables%3A%20Host%20variables%20in%20JSON%20or%20YAML%20format) says:

> Make a POST request to this resource with the following host fields to create a new host associated with this inventory.
>
> - `variables`: Host variables in JSON or YAML format. (json, default=``)

I also tried this way:

```yaml
- name: Add new host
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://{{ aap_fqdn }}/api/v2/inventories/{{ inventory }}/hosts/"
    user: '{{ user }}'
    password: '{{ pass }}'
    method: POST
    body:
      name: "host_1"
      ansible_host: "192.168.0.1"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
```

This actually worked for creating the host, but it didn't include the `ansible_host` variable and returned status code 201 instead of 200.

I also tried this way:

```yaml
- name: Add new host
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://{{ aap_fqdn }}/api/v2/inventories/{{ inventory }}/hosts/"
    user: '{{ user }}'
    password: '{{ pass }}'
    method: POST
    body:
      name: "host_1"
      variables: 'ansible_host=192.168.0.1'
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
```

This gave me this error:

```json
"json": {
  "variables": [
    "Cannot parse as JSON (error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)) or YAML (error: Input type `str` is not a dictionary)."
  ]
}
```

It seems like the first method would be the right way to do it so I can't figure out why it's not working. What am I doing wrong and what's the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `PUT` instead of `POST`?

Comment: according to the documentation it's `POST` since I'm creating a new host. If I were updating the host it'd be `PATCH` or `PUT`

Comment: Yeah.  I was reading the wrong api. But you do have this in your ansible code: `body_format: json`.  You are feeding it YAML. Not JSON

Comment: I'll try messing with that but I'm pretty sure ansible automatically converts the YAML to JSON.

Comment: Could you use the [awx collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ui/repo/published/awx/awx/)

Comment: @squashman `body_format: json` conveniently transforms a yaml body to pure JSON. See the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-body)